# What is the correct way to access a derived class object in a base class pointer container?

Tags: c++, stl, smart-pointers

I have a `vector<boost::shared_ptr<Base>>` object. I'm inserting an object of type `Derived` where `Derived` inherits `Base` like this: `container.push_back(boost::shared_ptr<Base>(new Derived()));`

I now want to call a function which takes a reference to a member of `Derived`, in order to modify this last entry I just inserted. This way, I don't end up creating a temporary instance of this `Derived` object. This is how I'm able to do it: `func(static_cast<Derived*>(&*container.back())->member);`

This looks really scary-ugly for me. But if I try to do `func(static_cast<Derived>(*container.back()).member);` instead, the compiler says I need to provide a ctor for `Derived` which takes the args `(const Base&)` in order to convert an instance of Base to an instance of Derived, which I don't need to do here... I just want to refer to my shared_ptr pointer as though it were a `Derived*` because I know it is because I just `new`ed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
vector<boost::shared_ptr<Base>> container;

shared_ptr<Derived> ptr(new Derived());
container.push_back(ptr);
func(ptr->member);
```

No casts. No temporaries of `Derived`.

Comment: I had to read the OPs question again carefully to see that this is indeed the best answer for that specific question. +1!

Comment: This looks great. I was unsure if I was allowed to do such a thing, I'm glad I can!!!

Answer (score 1):

I would use `dynamic_cast<>` as the object being stored may not actually be of type Derived (it may be a Derived_2 also derived from Base).

```
func(dynamic_cast<Derived&>(*container.back()).member)
```

You can also cast to references to make it look slightly neater.

Note: `dynamic_cast<>`

- if used to cast a pointer may return NULL
- if used to cast a reference may throw std::bad_cast

Which is why I prefer to use dynamic_cast with references usually. But if you use it with a pointer be sure to check the result is not NULL before you use it.

#### Edit on the updated question:

> But if I try to do func(static_cast(*container.back()).member);

You want a reference

```
static_cast<Derived&>
                  ^^^  Not the & here
```

This will stop it trying to call the constructor. If you static_cast<> to Derived it will try and create an object. What you really want is a reference.

Comment: He said he _knows_ that the type is a `Derived`; in this case, the `derived_cast` of the pointer is preferred, since it will (hopefully) result in an immediate crash if his knowledge is wrong.  (In fact, I've found almost no case where getting an exception from a `dynamic_cast` was appropriate behavior.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: I am not sure what a `derived_cast is` is this new in C++11? Also your interpretation of immediate crash is wrong (I assume you mean because of de-referencing a NULL pointer). This is merely undefined behavior and relying on that is ALWAYS wrong. An exception on the other hand will usually result in immediate application termination (after correctly unwinding the stack and cleaning up your resources like the open socket to the ISS).

Comment: `derived_cast` is a typo for `dynamic_cast`.  And yes, the idea is that you're dereferencing a null pointer.  Undefined behavior, but since you _know_ it can't happen...  (A better solution would be to assign the pointer, then `assert` that it is not null.)  And an exception can be caught and ignored (and may unwind the stack even if it isn't caught, which is highly undesirable).

Comment: @JamesKanze: If you deliberately go to the extra effort of catching an exception then you can definitely make the choice to ignore it, but you have made an explicit choice. I repeat: `relying on undefined behavior is **ALWAYS** wrong`. If you don't want exceptions then checking the pointer is the best solution (though I personally dislike (note dislike not don't use) assert (a personal trait (code that does not run in production is code that is useless and caches nothing (ie it must be combined with exhaustive tests) an exception can be caught and correctly logged in main))).

Comment: I wanted to avoid dynamic_cast and RTTI because of performance considerations: To this end I intend to use a member variable such as an enum in the base class which will specify the exact actual class (that enum will be assigned in the derived classes' ctors). Since I have that information available to me I am comfortable casting with impunity, though I'd like to do it "the right way" which i believe in C++ is using `static_cast` with references. (I have traditionally done a lot of "regular" casting of pointers) This answer has been helpful at showing me that, thanks.

Comment: @StevenLu: The correct way is dynamic_cast<>. You have to be doing an awful lot of casts to worry about performance (so that is a red-herring or a design flaw in your application, its like saying I don't want to use virtual functions because of the overhead (tough there is an overhead and you can't get around it (you may choose to pay for it in another way but you will pay, letting the compiler do the lifting means less chance of mistakes))). Using static_cast to cast away from the base class is wrong and will lead to errors (otherwise there would be no need for dynamic cast).

Comment: @StevenLu: Saying that. I do agree that your accepted answer solved all these problems quite nicely (no need for dynamic or static cast).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `static_pointer_cast` and `dynamic_pointer_cast` to cast between `shared_ptr`s:

```
shared_ptr<Derived> sp = static_pointer_cast<Derived>(container.back());
```